# How do I stop the text from overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal list on my page.

```
<ul class="period-selection">
    <li>Monthly</li>
    <li>Weekly</li>
    <li>Daily</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my css:

```
.period-selection {
  width: 33.3%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}
.period-selection li {
  float: left;
  width: 18%;
}
.period-selection li:last-child {
  margin-left: -12px;
}
```

As I collapse the page, the text start to overlap each other.  How do I keep the text separate or stop it from overlapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a fixed width of 33.33% for the li's, regardless of the length of the text within. Try setting it to auto.

And remove the

```
margin-left: -12px;
```

on the li:last-child.